# Eror in a code with beautiful soup, .gettext method

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am experiencing error with beautiful soup module. 
I was selecting some data on a website, and I can get data with tags, no issues there, but whenever I try it it fails, it treats variable like a list, although as I understood from bs4 it should not.

Here is the code:

```
   novsajt = requests.get(prpage, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
   novasupa = soup(novsajt.text, "html.parser")
   nesto = novasupa.find_all('p', class_='name product-title')

   for b_tag in nesto:
       for a_tag in b_tag:
            product_linkovi = a_tag['href']
            source11 = requests.get(product_linkovi, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla5.0'})
            soup11 = soup(str(source11), "html.parser")
            productName = soup11.select("main#main h1").get_text() 
            listaproizvoda.append("productName" + str(productName)+ ";")
            synonims = soup11.select("main#main div.product-short-description > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of-type(2)").get_text()
            listaproizvoda.append("synonims" +  str(synonims)+ ";")
            Application = soup11.select("main#main div.product-short-description > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(2)").get_text()
            listaproizvoda.append("Application" + str(Application)+ ";")
```

So, how do you recommend extraction of text without tags? What type of mistake I am making?

Comment: When you do a `select()`, it always returns a list regardless of the number of items parsed.  You'll need to iterate through that list to parse the data.

If you do a `select_one()` however, it will return one single object as you expected.

Comment: Just tried it, does not work, here is the eerror:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\untitled3\sraper.py", line 34, in <module>
    productName = soup11.select_one("main#main h1").get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: Looks like your `select_one()` is not returning anything (hence `None`).  Have you verified the data are actually returned?

Comment: yes, when i do .select, it returns me element with wrapped tags, here is output:
<a href="https://www.antibodygenie.com/product/tnfsf10-antibody-fitc-conjugated/">TNFSF10 Antibody FITC conjugated</a>
product done<a href="https://www.antibodygenie.com/product/tnfsf10-antibody-hrp-conjugated/">TNFSF10 Antibody HRP conjugated</a>

Comment: you are right it selects nothing @Idlehands

Comment: worked, cheers mate!

Comment: You did all the hard work, all I did was pointed out where you need to pay attention.  Give yourself a pat on the back!